# Label won't change after a condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, label

I have this:

```
word_count = 0
max_words = 12

global max_words
global word_count

while word_count < max_words:

        if word_count == max_words:
                time_Label.config(text="You did it in: " + str(time_score))
                label.config(text="FINISHED")
```

I'm curious as to why what is written on both labels won't change when `word_count == max_words`

If it helps:

```
time_Label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Time: " + str(time_score) + "s", font=('Helvetica', 14))
time_Label.pack()

label = tkinter.Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 60))
label.pack()
```

Comment: not an expert on tkinter, but I'd suggest starting by storing the label's text in a textvariable linked to a tkinter StringVar.

Comment: Where are you setting word_count?

Also, if wourd_count is equal to max_words, it will not enter the while loop and thus never execute the if checking to see if it is equal to max_words.

Comment: `if entry.get().lower() == random_word.lower(): word_count += 1` This increases `word_count` if the user types what's on the screen correctly. This doesn't work either `word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))`

Comment: @BlivetWidget: you don't need a textvariable for this to work.

Comment: @BryanOakley not saying you do, just that tkinter doesn't follow a lot of Python conventions, so working with tkinter objects will make life easier.

Comment: @BlivetWidget: the use of a text viable has nothing to do with python conventions. You can change a label without using textvariable and still "[work] with tkinter objects". Using textvariable just adds an intermediate object you have to maintain. You can directly change the actual object text rather than change the value of an associated label.

Comment: @BryanOakley the relevance is that you can change the StringVar like a normal Python variable, while changing properties of many tkinter objects requires more obtuse approaches like label["text"] or label.config(text).  Whether or not you know how to use them, the fact is that many beginners find that to be more difficult.

Comment: @BlivetWidget: _"the relevance is that you can change the StringVar like a normal Python variable"_ - no, you can't. To change the value of a `StringVar` requires a function call (`my_var.set(...)`).  So, with or without `StringVar`, you have to use a function call to change the text of a label.

Comment: @BryanOakley ah yes, that's right.  One of those things I always end up rediscovering whenever I use tkinter.  Still of the opinion that if it followed normal conventions, there would just be a Label.text property you'd use.

Comment: Getting back to my computer, I now remember why I prefer using the textvariables: the different tkinter objects often require different methods to update their text.  If linked to a StringVar, the StringVar is always updated the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while word_count < max_words:

        if word_count == max_words:
```

The inner check will never be called, since the only way to get there is if `word_count` is less than `max_words`. And if it's less than, it can't be equal to.